# How to display 0000 format in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to write the dino game and score is 00000

```
doubl intialScore = 0000;

void calculatingScore() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 3000), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        initalScore == initalScore++;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to "pad" the string, just do the following:
`'$score'.padLeft(5, '0')`
So, with the input `1`, the output will be `00001`, with the input `10`, the output will be `00010`, and if you wanna add or remove the padded 0, just set the first argument of padLeft to a higher / lower number, so:
`'$score'.padLeft(4, '0')`, with an input of `1`, will give you `0010`